# Extract a specific word from a text in java

Tags: java

I want to extract a particular word from a text using `Java`. Is it possible

e.g. :

```
String str = "this is 009876 birthday of mine";
```

I want to get '009876' from above text in `Java`. Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you heard of Regex?

Comment: Easy, just do: `String result = "009876";`

Comment: If you know the word it's easy yes and otherwise if you are always looking for a number check  [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) !
Clarify your question.

Comment: The word "particular word" is vague. Flagging to close this question

Comment: How to know which word to extract? If we already know which word to extract, do we only need to determine its position in the string.

Comment: i wants to get only 009876 out of the whole text.. i know that this 009876 is there in the whole text so .. i just wants to extract it eliminating the all other text ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by regex. Below is an example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "this is 009876 birthday of mine";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("009876");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(hello);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;

        System.out.println(count);    // prints 1
    }
}
```

If you want to check if the text contains the source string (e.g. "009876") you can do it simply by contains method of String as shown in below example:

```
public static String search() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = "this is 009876 birthday of mine";
        String source = "009876";
        if(text.contains(source))
            return text;
        else
            return text;

    }
```

Let me know if any issue.

Comment: The question isn't asking how to count the number of instances of a specific substring. And it isn't asking how to check if it contains a subsring either

Comment: i am not asking what is the position for string 009876.. i wan to extract only 009876 from the whole text .. i wants to eliminate all other .. sop i have source as 009876 and i wants to math this source with the given text.. if it matches then return that text...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  class ExtractDesiredString{
      
    static String extractedString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "this is 009876 birthday of mine";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("009876");

        if (hello.contains(pattern.toString())) {
            extractedString = pattern.toString();
        }else{
            Assert.fail("Given string doesn't contain desired text")
        }
    }
}
```